# Import CSV into Apache Ignite

Tags: java, csv, ignite

What would be a way to import directly data from CSV file with e.g. 10 columns (ID, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Email, HomePhone, CellPhone, Address, Location, DOB) and 10 rows into Apache Ignite cache?

Should fields be predefined before entering data to cache? Can fields be dynamically set based on input file (e.g. first line)?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read this data from CSV and stream it into the cache with [DataStreamer](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-streamers), it will be the fastest way.

It's possible to create cache and define it fields [dynamically](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jcache#section-dynamic-cache)

It's possible to work without POJO class at all if you use [BinaryObjects](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller)

Also, if you will need to use this cache with SQL, you will need to define [QueryEntity](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes#section-queryentity-based-configuration) before cache creating

Comment: Thanks. Does query entity needs to be set in XML form like in that example or can it be set programmatically inside Java code based on some field name? (and do you have example of how to set it programmatically)

Comment: It's possible to set it programmatically too, here is an example: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/binary/datagrid/CacheClientBinaryQueryExample.java